# LVM snapshot size

Tags: lvm

I currently have 2 volume's:

```
  [root@compute4 /]# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vps/vm108_img' [30.00 GB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vps/vm109_img' [90.00 GB] inherit
```

Now, I use the LVM snapshot function to create backups. My quesion is, what size does the snapshot needs to be? Atleast the same as the volume in question **or** can it be a lot smaller and will only the changes be saved into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only need to assign the amount of space for changes to happen. From [a recipe in the docs](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html):

> A snapshot volume can be as large or a small as you
>   like **but it must be large enough to hold all the changes that are
>   likely to happen** to the original volume during the lifetime of the
>   snapshot.

However, be sure to allocate enough space:

> If the snapshot logical volume becomes full it will be dropped (become unusable) so it is vitally important to allocate enough space.